# SQL Server 2008 - Transaction per second for specific database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Does any one know how to measure the SQL transactions per second for a specifc database in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
DECLARE @cntr_value bigint

SELECT @cntr_value = cntr_value
    FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
    WHERE counter_name = 'transactions/sec'
        AND object_name = 'SQLServer:Databases'
        AND instance_name = 'YourDatabase'

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'

SELECT cntr_value - @cntr_value
    FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
    WHERE counter_name = 'transactions/sec'
        AND object_name = 'SQLServer:Databases'
        AND instance_name = 'YourDatabase'
```

Comment: When I run this I get a value of 426836. Is that the transactions per second? Seems quite high.

Comment: @izip: The value for "per second" counters is cumulative. You would need to take the difference of two values for a fixed time interval to get the # of transactions for that time interval. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that came back as 10 which seems more reasonable!

Comment: Joe, for `object_name` I see `MSSQL$<instance_name>:Databases` instead of `SQLServer:Databases`. I'd update your query to make that clear.

Comment: The code is the missing reference to the original blog post: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/10/04/sql-server-find-total-number-of-transaction-on-interval/

Answer (score 0):

The procedures sp_BlitzFirst located at https://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/ returns this information at the database level, along with a lot of other great information. A simple call like the following will show you what happens over the course of 5 seconds.

```
EXEC dbo.sp_BlitzFirst @ExpertMode = 1, @seconds = 5;
```